# Android:Got NumberFormatExxception while getting data from EditText field

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo { com.project/com.project.simple} : java.lang.NumberFormatException

```
EditText et1,et2,et3;
Button b1, b2;
Float two,three,four;   
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.can);

et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

two = Float.valueOf(et1.getText().toString());

et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

three = Float.valueOf(et2.getText().toString());

et3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

four = Float.valueOf(et3.getText().toString());

    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the input is not valid. Please check twice that you don't try to parse a letters to a number. If you have a float please check that you use the right locale for parsing. E.g. in germany is pi 3,1415... and not 3.1415...

If you cannot preparse the values you could put the parsing trys in try catch blocks like this:

```
float value;
try {
    value=Float.parseFloat(someString);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    // input was no valid float
}
```

Comment: Not entered any input...in this project getting values externally.

Comment: In this case put the `Float.valueOf()` statements in try catch blocks

Answer (score 0):

you are in `onCreate()` where the fields are specified. the user could not have time to enter any valid data. you need to move the fetching of the data somewhere else...like your `onClick()` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

move your code from onCerate to an other method 
(for example the onClick method of the Button ) 
and you should
try this:

```
try{
   two = Float.parseFloat(et1.getText().toString());
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
   two = 0;       
   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, 'Invalid number format on `two` field', 500);
   toast.show();  
}
```

For each text fields what you want to read
Comment:
float format is 2.3 and don't use 2,3