# How to resolve this Null pointer exception?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I got an error at `principal==0.0` and I don't understand why this happened.

```
if(et1.getText()!=null) {
    try {
        principal = Double.valueOf(et1.getText().toString());
}
catch(Exception e) {
    message = "Incorrect value";
}
}
// The problem is in the if statement below!
if(principal==0.00) {
    message = "value cannot be zero";
    title = "error";
}
```

The error I get is the following:

```
   01-31 22:21:37.700: E/AndroidRuntime(985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   01-31 22:21:37.700: E/AndroidRuntime(985):
   java.lang.NullPointerException 01-31 22:21:37.700:
   E/AndroidRuntime(985):   at
   com.compoundinterest.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:65)
   01-31 22:21:37.700: E/AndroidRuntime(985):   at
   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485) 01-31 22:21:37.700:
   E/AndroidRuntime(985):   at
   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080) 01-31
   22:21:37.700: E/AndroidRuntime(985):     at
   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587) 01-31
   22:21:37.700: E/AndroidRuntime(985):     at
   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 01-31
   22:21:37.700: E/AndroidRuntime(985):     at
   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) 01-31 22:21:37.700:
   E/AndroidRuntime(985):   at
   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) 01-31
   22:21:37.700: E/AndroidRuntime(985):     at
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

What might be the cause of this error and how do I solve it?

Comment: I assume that the `**` are just in your code to highlight the relevant section? If so, please don't do that. Add a proper code comment if you must, but don't add content that would otherwise result in faulty code.

Comment: @Bart:just i highlighted that code

Comment: Okay, please don't do that. Just add a comment or something. For example `//The problem is in the line below`. That is still clear and we can actually copy-paste the code to test if needed, without any problems.

Comment: Possible duplicates by the same user: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14627264/199048 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/14569340/199048 .

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
// Declaration on top
Double principal=0.00;
```

Use this :

```
EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEdit);

if(!et1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
    try {
        principal = Double.parseDouble(et1.getText().toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        message = "Incorrect value";
    }
}

if(principal==0.00) {
    message = "value cannot be zero";
    title = "error";
}
```

Comment: can i use instead Double.parseDouble of new Double

Comment: @user2019287 you mean to say like this `new Double(string);`?

Comment: if(principalTxt.getText()!=null){
    try{
    principal=new Double(principalTxt.getText().toString());
    }
 catch(Exception E){
 message=message+"Unexpected value for initial deposit.\n";
 title="Error!"; 
 }
 }

Comment: @user2019287 you can use that too but it will a good practice to use `Double.parseDouble` rather than calling constructors.

Comment: But using parsedouble or any thing else im getting same problem at principal==0.0

Comment: @user2019287 have you declare principal variable before using this `Double principal=0.0;` and try to check condition like this `if(principal==0)`.

Comment: @Pratik: Why should one initialize it with 0.0? Maybe 0.0 is a valid input, then you can't distinguish "undefined" from "0.0". The OP is actually initializing it with null as you can see in his three other questions about the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more it's hard to tell. My guess is that if et1.getText() == null then principal is never initialized.

Comment: Right, but what IS principal? Is it a null value when you're comparing it because the code above didn't initialize it? It's hard to tell why that would happen without knowing more, but that seems to be what is going on.

Comment: values must be entered externally so i have placed != operator and 0.0 values . for occuring that values

Answer (score 0):

When an exception occurs during `valueOf` your variable `principal` won't be set. And the comparsion will throw a NullPointerException, because it is auto-unboxing `principal` to a double, which cannot be null.

Therefore it should be

```
if (principal == null) {
  // error handling
} else if (principal==0.00) {
```

And check you logs for previous exceptions during `valueOf`.

---

I know it's your fourth question to same problem and you just copied your code from [Kovge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14569435/199048). You would be learning more, if you would try to understand the given answers.

Here are some variants for your copy-and-paste approach:

1. Ignoring null values explicitly:

   ```
   if (principal == null && principal==0.00) {
   ```
2. Ignoring null values by using Doubles:

   ```
   if (Double.valueOf(0.0).equals(principal)) {
   ```

Comment: If everything is fine, why would you get a NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0):

Seems principal is null.

When you do this check.

```
if(principal==0.00)
```

It actually is

```
if(principal.doubleValue() ==0.00)
```

And this cause the nullPointer because the principal is null.

So change it to:

```
if(principal ==null)
//return or do something
else if(principal ==0.00)
```